# Why static library not working?

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, static-linking, unresolved-external

I tried making this simple static library in Code::Blocks with MinGW:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "header.h"

extern int go(int x)
{
  struct timeval t;
  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  return 1;
}
```

This same snippet works if compiled as a console app *(with printf)*, but when compiled as a static library, the calling code keeps getting this error:

```
unresolved external symbol "_gettimeofday"
```

Comment: `gettimeofday` is not a standard C function, it might not be available. I don't have enough experience with MinGW to answer this question completely though.

Comment: Hi. So you mean that this would only occur with non-standard libraries? How could we ensure that such libraries are linked then?

Comment: Usually you would supply the flag `-l<library>` to the compiler but I'm not sure how this works on Windows.